# Let $d:A→\mathbb{Z}$ be a positive definite quadratic form, then $d(mφ)＝m^2d(φ)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, bilinear-form

Let $A$ be an abelian group. $A$ function $d : A → R$
is a quadratic form if it satisfies the following conditions:
(i) $d(α)=d(−α)$ for all $α∈A$.
(ii) The pairing
$A × A → R$ , $( α , β )  → d ( α + β ) − d ( α ) − d ( β )$ , is bilinear.
A quadratic form $d$ is positive definite if it further satisfies: (iii)$ d(α)≥0$ for all $α∈A$.
(iv) $d(α)=0$ ifandonlyif $α=0$.

My question:

Let $d:A→\mathbb{Z}$ be a positive definite quadratic form, and let $n$ be integer, and $φ∈A$, then does
$d(mφ)＝m^2d(φ)$ hold?

This problem appeared in the process of proving causy Schwarz inequality of positive difinitequadratic version.